# How we can add multiple android.gradle_dependencies in buildozer specs. file

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

In the following code I have only added one android gradle dependencies in buildozer specs file, but I want to add one more
**'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:18.1.1'** , I want to add this also, how to add this in the following code.
code : **android.gradle_dependencies = 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'**

please any one say how to add multiple gradle dependencies in buildozer specs file.

Comment: please answer anyone

Answer (score 0):

```
android.gradle_dependencies
```

is a List, so I think you can separate each dependency with a comma:

```
android.gradle_dependencies = 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0','com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:18.1.1'
```